# URI Online Judge - 1168 - Java

Tags: java, string

Estou tentando resolver o problema 1168 do URI. Porém, não estou conseguindo obter o número de leds necessários para montar um número. Especificamente, a minha variável `valorLed` está sempre resultando em zero. Podem me ajudar?

Problema: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1168

Meu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = sc.next();
        String v = sc.next();

        /* matriz faz a correspondencia entre um algarismo e a 
        quantidade de led necessaria p/ monta-lo */
        char [][] matriz = {{0,6}, {1,2}, {2,5}, {3,5}, {4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6}, {7,3}, {8,7}, {9,6}};
        char[] listV = v.toCharArray();

        //valorLed eh a variavel responsavel por armazenar o numero de leds necessarios
        int valorLed = 0;

        for(int linha = 0; linha < 9; linha++){
            for(int x = 0; x < listV.length; x++ ){
                if(matriz[linha][0] == listV[x]){
                    valorLed += (int) matriz[linha][1];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(valorLed);
    }
}
```

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Com certeza é porque o bloco dentro do if nunca é executado. Aliás, coloque seu código aqui, é bom ter um lugar para testar, mas também é preciso ter o código aqui.

Comment: jbueno, por que o bloco dentro do if nunca é executado, no meu caso?

Comment: Não sei, jovem. Eu coloquei um `println` de teste ali dentro pra testar e vi que ele não era executado. Até tentei ver o motivo, mas no momento estou sem tempo.

Comment: sugiro usar o fórum do URI (http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/forum/), alguém já pode ter a mesmo dúvida que você em algum momento.

Comment: eu acho que tem um for e um if sobrando no código, mas sem ver o problema original fica dificil. A impressão que dá é que bastaria um for correndo todos os caracteres, e somando o respectivo indice da matriz correspondendo ao numero, apenas isso: `for i = 0 to tamanho da string, numero = caractere[i] da string convertido, leds += matriz[ numero ][1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numa olhada por cima encontrei três erros. Não sei se são os únicos.

1. Você só está pegando um único valor `v`. Deveria pegar `n` valores `v`. Ou seja, deveria ter algo assim:

   ```
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       String v = sc.next();
       processarValor(v);
   }
   ```
2. Seu primeiro `for` está indo até `linha < 9`. Acho que deveria ir até `linha <= 9`.
3. Usar `listV[x]` não vai funcionar porque essa posição não estará guardando os valores no intervalo de 0 a 9 e sim de 48 a 57 (ou 0x30 a 0x39 em hexadecimal), que são os valores ASCII dos caracteres `'0'` a `'9'` obtidos com a transformação `toCharArray()`. Uma maneira rápida de fazer funcionar é trocando `listV[x]` por `(listV[X] - 48)`.

Uma dica: seu array `matriz` não precisa ser bidimensional. Os dígitos `0` a `9` já correspondem aos índices de um array unidimensional normal. Então você poderia ter algo assim:

```
char [] matriz = { 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6 };
```

E poderia descobrir o número de leds necessários para formar o dígito 9 assim:

```
matriz[9]; // número de leds necessário = 6
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Dúvida sanada